# VBA - Split, copy and paste characters from string into another cell (with conditions)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm at the beginning with VBA and struggling with a worksheet that need to be cleaned up.
I have a column with strings that mix zipcodes and city names. I want to extract from column A the zipcode and place in column B, and the city name with underscore in column C.

My (example) input:

```
A 
55442
11211
1
12
11211_brooklyn
1002_new_york
new_york
brooklyn
```

What I want

```
A
55442
11211
1
12
11211_brooklyn
1002_new_york
new_york
brooklyn

B
55442
11211
1
12
11211
1002


C




brooklyn
new_york
new_york
brooklyn
```

I understand how to extract characters with the Left formula but it's not enough.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
B2:
=IF(ISNUMBER(A2),A2,IFERROR(1*LEFT(A2,FIND("_",A2)-1),""))

C2:
=MID(A2, 1+LEN(B2)+ISNUMBER(B2),99)
```

[image]

EDIT - As it appears that there are cases like `00010_alaska`; zip codes that include leading zeros, this should be used instead for column `C`:

```
C2:
=IF(B2="",A2, IFERROR(MID(A2,1+FIND("_",A2),99),""))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I've noticed that if the zipcode starts with "0" like 00010_alaska, I get in the zipcode column "10" and in the city column "10_alaska". Any suggestion how i could fix it?

Comment: @Alberto.F. try the edit to deal with this special case.

Answer (score 1):

in A column put your source list
in B column (zip code) put formula:

```
=IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(TRIM(LEFT($A1,FIND("_",$A1,1)-1))),"")
```

in C column (city) put formula

```
=IF(ISNUMBER($B1),RIGHT($A1,LEN($A1)-FIND("_",$A1,1)),$A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through and used helper columns to determine if the data started with a number. If it did, I figured out if it also had a name in it. I then returned either the full data set or the data set truncated until the city name respectively. Column B:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(INT(MID(A1,1,1))),MID(A1,1,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("_",A1)),LEN(A1),SEARCH("_",A1)-1)),"")
```

Then I went through and determined if the data started with something other than a number. If it did, it was a city and I used the whole dataset for that record. If not, I tested to see if it had an underscore. If it did, there was a city present. I then used helper columns to determine where that underscore began and returned the city name. I left blanks in the helper columns to get only a single name or not. Then, I concatenated it all to get my final answer. The resulting super formula is this:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(INT(MID(A1,1,1)))),A1,""),IF(IF(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(INT(MID(A1,1,1)))),A1,"")="",IFERROR(SEARCH("_",A1),""),"")="","",MID(A1,IF(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(INT(MID(A1,1,1)))),A1,"")="",IFERROR(SEARCH("_",A1),""),"")+1,LEN(A1))))
```

It is ugly, but it will get the job done. I would recommend copying and pasting directly into the worksheet instead of using VBA. But, if you must use VBA, loop through column B and C and apply the formulas provided into the cell formula property. I hope that helps.